# Working with 2 different python environment for a same project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on a project that requires two different version of Python (Python 3.x & Python 2.x). I have installed Python 2.x in my local Windows machine. However, for some packages, it requires 3.x (or simply it gives errors when I installed in the 2.x environment). How can I resolve this?
Sorry if my question is too naive. Thanks!

Comment: You can run Python 2 and Python 3 side by side, independent of each other. If you install packages for either of them, each packages needs to be separately installed for each version. If done right, Python will keep the versions apart and use the correct packages.

Comment: Your third sentence is a bit unclear: are you saying that you need to install packages that don't run or can't be installed under Python 2?

Comment: Note that Python 2 has reached end of life over a year ago, and is not supported anymore. (Major) packages have followed suit, and also dropped support for Python 2. Thus, installing Python 2 is absolutely disadvised, especially if you can also use Python 3. You may be able to adjust the Python 2 code under Python 3 (using the `2to3` tool, for example), but the project maintainers should do that.

Comment: @00 thanks!! I tested with your first suggestions. it works